# Nextcloud Mail not accessible using TLS

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, nextcloud

I configured my mail server on my server using Postfix and dovecot. SMTP and IMAP Server works well whan using the commands
`openssl s_client -connect localhost:143 -starttls imap`
and `openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -starttls smtp`. I used Let's Encrypt Certificates. But when I set the same credentials in nexcloud there is always the log **Creating account failed: Could not open secure TLS connection to the server.** I suspect that nextcloud is not trusting my certificate. When I disable TLS I can authentificate in Nexcloud

```
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mail.example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=mail.example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGWzCCBUOgAwIBAgISA0ajSksNknzQ2+R7wK9h1J2HMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
<TRUNCATE>
FMSZwZRGt2I1pTSafXsqRNzryHrc5ZQVgpsqHQnmGWnpg9I4Lv7glSg7dY+/bbE=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=mail.example.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3955 bytes and written 450 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 309CFB94430523ABFC29179E5003A74CB332CDC4F6A975AFCCE12C3A45EC33D4
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: ***
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 3600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 50 f3 2e 9a 1e 01 04 3c-86 8e f8 c7 f0 50 1a 3d   P......<.....P.=
    <TRUNCATE>
    0090 - a4 93 ea 18 9e 0b 7b f1-2d 97 be cf fe 8b f3 4e   ......{.-......N

    Start Time: 1597921756
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 DSN
```

For TLS on Postfix side I set the main.cf

```
#TLS
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file =  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_disable_workarounds = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
#smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDB3-SHA, KRB5-DES, CBC3-SHA
#smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/dhparam/dh1024.pem
#smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = ultra
```

[image]

Comment: Check Nextcloud's logs.

Comment: Can you try using a different port for SMTP? Like 587 submission?
IMAP should be over TLS aswell, and that is port 993.

Comment: Nextcloud.log gives just spare information, only that TLS ist not secure.

Comment: Yes Port 993 is working as well, IMAP was not the real problem I think. It's the SMTP which is problematic

Comment: Wait port 587 does not seems to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STARTTLS runs when I actually type my host mail.example.com but does not work with localhost. I run this mail client from a subdomain cloud.example.com, it seems that cloud.example.com does not find the localhost mail.example.com